# How to sort by a derived value that includes a moving date in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement to sort the results returned by ElasticSearch by a special value i define, let's call it 'X'.

Now - the problem is, 'X' is a value derived based on:

- field A in the document (which is a 'term')
- field B (which is a 'date')
- the current date (UTC)

So, the problem is obviously 3. The date always changes, therefore i'm not sure how to include this in the sort, since it's not part of the document.

From my initial reading it appears i can use a 'script' here, but i'm worried about the performance, since i could be searching + sorting over 1000's of documents.

The only other idea that came to mind is to calculate the value nightly, and store that in each document. But that has a few drawbacks:

- i need to have something running in the background to update this value
- could be a lot of documents to update (60%+ every night).
- i lose precision for the value depending on how long between script runs. (if i run nightly, value is 23 hours 'stale')

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: So, did you try to do script score? Did it cause you a problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by having an ES script run nightly calculating value, and store that in each document